# Mostrar os três veículos mais bem avaliados de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um site para o curso, porém estou com um problema. Optei em usar duas tabelas, uma para as "classificações", e outra para os "veículos". Gostaria então, de selecionar os 3 veículos mais bem avaliados da tabela, e que ele seja mostrado na página principal.

Tabela "classificacoes":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDriQ.png

Tabela "veiculos":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwxxQ.png

Obs: O id_veiculo da tabela 'classificacoes' é o mesmo id da outra tabela.

Comment: quem ser mais avaliados?

Answer (score 1):

testa ai:

```
select vec.nome, classic.nome from veiculos as vec
inner join classificacoes as classic
on classic.id_veiculos = vec.id
where classic.estrelas > 3
order by classic.estrelas asc
```

Infelizmente não estou conseguindo acessar meu banco de dados no momento, mas isso deve resolver. Levando em considaração que a númeração relevante de estrelas seja maior que 3.

Comment: essa consulta vai retornar os veículos com mais de 3 estrelas e não é isso o que ele pediu.

Answer (score 0):

Para a consulta retornar apenas os 3 veículos mais bem avaliados:

```
select * from classificacoes order by estrelas desc limit 3
```

Usando join entre as tabelas, seria assim:

```
select * from classificacoes c, veiculos v
where c.id_veiculo = v.id
order by c.estrelas desc limit 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05dbb2/1